# Optimize GROUPBY in PySpark to run faster

Tags: python, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, group-by

```
df_grouped = (
    df.groupBy("Date", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
    .agg(
        first("M").alias("M"),
        first("N").alias("N"),
        first("O").alias("O"),
        first("P").alias("P"),
        first("Q").alias("Q"),
        first("R").alias("R"),
        first("S").alias("S")
    )
    .withColumn("Year", year(col("Date")))
    .withColumn("Month", month(col("Date")))
    .select("Date", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S" "Year", "Month")
    .filter(col("Date") >= date_sub(current_date(), 600))
)
```

Hello,

I have a code as shown above, it takes a lot of time to run when there are billions row. May I know how can I optimize this code so that it can run more efficiently and faster? I have been searching around the alternative method but couldn't find any, appreciate any help or advise, thank you!

Comment: it might be the case of bad partitioning. if the input source is from a different process, try to partition it based on downstream consumptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to observe the data distribution during during runtime for each task on Spark UI. if observe uneven distribution of data among the partitions, then you may need to use bucketing, repartitioning to evenly distribute the data.
2. Try to partition the data based on columns used in group by condition. This will group the data with same grouping key column into same partition and will reduce data shuffling occuring during runtime.
3. Apply filtering condition before `groupBy` operation to reduce the amount of data processed during aggregation operation.
4. Select only required columns for analysis. this will to reduce the amount of the data processed during group by.